# How to inherit a standard Fluid component and override and replace some equations of the base model?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to customize a standard Fluid Library component in Modelica using OpenModelica.

I want to create a customized version of a new Pump where several equations will be changed.

I inherited `Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PartialPump` as a base model by "extends" keyword. When I tried to change and redefine an equation, it gave an overdetermined system error. 
I put redeclare or redifine in front of the equation, and it still gives an error.

What is the best way to create a customised component model without copying everything into a new model?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot change existing code* — you can only add new code.

In your case, you will have to make a copy of `Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PartialPump` and modify the equation in question. However, you don't necessarily need to copy its base class (`Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialTwoPort`).

The `PartialPump` model is quite versatile. If you need different pump curves (pressure, efficiency or power) you can write additional functions based on the   base classes in `Fluid.Machines.BaseClasses.PumpCharacteristics`.

*) One exception to my initial statement is the inheritance of graphical annotations: if you extend a model and add the annotation `primitivesVisible=false` the graphical annotations (icon) will not be inherited, for example:

```
model myModel
  extends baseModel annotation(IconMap(primitivesVisible=false));

  <new icon annotations>
end myModel;
```

Comment: Another exception regarding changing existing code is 'selective model extension' that has recently been added to the Modelica specification. However, that only allows you to remove components and connections - not other equations.

Answer (score 5):

The usage of `extends` suggests one wants to inherit all the behaviours of the extended class. You can change those behaviours unless they are `redeclarable`. The best is to create a new class by duplicating the base model and then change the behaviours as you want. Hope this works!

[image: Duplicate a class in OpenModelica]